# Magnitude of the energy gap

Tags: solid-state-physics

First of all, I'm using the book "Introduction to Solid-State Physics", by Charles Kittel, 8th edition. At chapter 7, page 167, he is assuming he has a lattice with parameter a. After that he writes:
"Let us suppose that the potential energy of an electron in the crystal at point x is:
$$U(x)=U\cos(\frac{2 \pi x}{a})$$

To me, this seems wrong, I thought we interpreted the ion-cores as positive and the electrons as negative, what he is saying is that the electrons should have a maximum in potential energy at x=a, I would claim the opposite, shouldn't the electrons have their max at $x=\frac{a}{2}$ ?

Comment: The positive charges are at positions ..., -a, 0, a, ... (with +U) while he electrons are at positions ... -a/2, a/2, ... (with -U)

Comment: But shouldnt the potential energy be higher the further i am from the positive ion?

Comment: Why can you  say that the electrons already are at -a/2, a/2 etc?

Comment: Perhaps U <0 ? (need to add extra characters...)

Comment: You are right in saying that the positive ions should have -U instead, but the interpretation does not affect the math. It is a model to illustrate bandgap from a periodic potential using the central equation, i.e. to model this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Potential-actual.PNG

Comment: I am saying that the electrons should have $U<0$ so the minimum is at x=0 or any other multiple of a.